# Should a decorated function know about its decorator from a semantic point of view?

Tags: python, static-typing

In this toy example `some_function` is... some function that takes a dict as an input and modifies it in place somehow.

```py
def some_function(dct: dict):
    """Do something to the items in the dictionary.

    Args:
        dct: A dict that ... some description.
    """
```

I happen to know the caller of this function will often (but not always) have a list of dicts to do this with.

The caller could do:

```py
ls_dct: list[dict]
for dct in ls_dct
    some_function(dct)
```

but this happens so often that I wanted to make it easier. I could do something like:

```py
def some_function_with_maybe_loop(dct_or_dcts: dct | list[dct]):
    """Do something to the items in the dict(s).

    Args:
        list: A dict or list of dicts that ... some description. If there is a lists of dicts, all the dicts are
            processed independently in a for-loop.
    """
    if isinstance(dct_or_dcts, dict):
        dct_or_dcts = [dct_or_dcts]
    for dct in dct_or_dcts:
        # do something
```

but I have lots of these sorts of functions and I don't want to have to repeat that logic. So **instead**, I could make a decorator:

```py
def maybe_process_multiple_dicts(f: Callable[[dict], None]) -> Callable[[dict | list[dict]], None]:
    """Decorator that takes a function that works with a single dict and makes it work with a list of dicts.

    This works by wrapping the function in a for-loop over the dicts.
    """

    def wrapped(dct_or_dcts: dict | list[dict]):
        if isinstance(dct_or_dcts, list):
            for dct in dct_or_dcts:
                f(dct)
        else:
            f(dct_or_dcts)

    return wrapped


@maybe_process_multiple_dicts
def some_function(dct: dict):
    """Do something to the items in the list

    Args:
        list: A dict that ... some description.
    """
```

**But now I have a dilemma**. The docstring for `some_function` and the argument name are both wrong. They should match that of `some_function_with_maybe_loop`. So should I update the docstring to reflect the modification imposed by the decorator? And supposing the answer is yes, then what should I do with the argument type-hint. For the type-hinting to all work it should stay as just `dct: dict`, but for the semantics to work it should be `dct: dict | list[dict]`.

Comment: Remember that the decoration effectively does `some_function = maybe_process_multiple_dicts(some_function)`, so the resulting value `some_function` has no docstring and its signature _is_ `dct_or_dcts: dict | list[dict]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh that's even worse. Then the decorating function would have to adopt the decorated function's documentation and append some of its own.

Comment: Yes, that's what [`functools.wrapped`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is for.

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend *not* accepting a single dict or list of dicts. Define a function that takes a list, and the caller can pass a singleton list if necessary. Your decorator is then little more than the built-in `map` function/class.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough situation where no answer is completely right.

I would definitely keep the `dict` annotation, because otherwise it doesn't match the behaviour of the function it is attached to, maybe with a comment explaining how that annotation doesn't match the annotation of the decorated function.

In terms of documentation, that should document how the function is used, not how it is implemented. So as counter-intuitive as it may be, I would suggest something like this:

```
@maybe_process_multiple_dicts
def some_function(dct: dict):
    # NOTE: the decorated function also accepts a list of dicts, which calls this function multiple times
    """Do something to the items in the dict or list of dicts

    Args:
        list: A dict or list of dicts that ... some description. If there is a lists of dicts, all the dicts are
            processed independently in a for-loop."""
```